# Converting/parsing query results to string .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2. I want to convert the data i get from my database to string. 
This is my **Dish** model

```
public class Dish
 {
     public int DishID { get; set; }
     public decimal? DishPrice { get; set; }
 }
```

And this is **MyController**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult MyView() 
    {
         var Dishes = _context.Dish.OrderBy(d =>d.DishID).ToList();
         return View(Dishes)
    }
}
```

And finally here is **MyView**

```
@model Dish
  foreach(var a in Model)
  {
     <h1> @a.DishPrice </h1>
  }
```

The problem is when I check the DishPrice data type, it's decimal. I want all data which controller passes to the view be a string.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a string at that point? You can convert it into another model which has them as strings if you really need that, but why can’t the view convert them to what is needed?

Comment: Becasue if an admin adds a DishPrice with a number like this 002300, the decmial  and int will remove the zero before 2300. So MyView shows 2300 rather than 002300. And also if i register it in a model with string type its impossible to do mathmatical operations on it

Comment: Why do preceding zeroes matter on a price? If it’s always a number of digits you can format it as such. Or you’ll have to save it in two forms.

Comment: Create a ViewModel whichs suits you needs, and after loading data convert from your DB-Model to your ViewModel. Things are done then, and you can do every conversion you need in your ViewModel. Doing it that way you're are also seperating your db layer from your view layer. Currently you're mixing stuff.

Comment: @ArianShahalami I suspect you need to clarify the requirements. Leading zeros in numbers *don't* matter. If you want to display numbers a certain way, use `String.Format` or `ToString()` and specify the format you want in the view itself. There's no reason to change `DishPrice` to a string

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It doesn't matter for prices. but I'm curious about that. If a client asked me to add zeros before that what should I do.

Comment: @ArianShahalami You could change your header to `<h1>@a.DishPrice?.ToString("00000.00")</h1>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This manual. so I have to manually add `ToString` to all fields in all views :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You could convert the `@Model` before iteration. Seems that your Model should be `IQueryable<Dish>`</strike> :

```
@model IQueryable<Dish>

foreach(var a in Model.Select(d => new {DishId = d.DishID, DishPrice = String.Format("{0:00000.00}",d.DishPrice)}))
{
    <h1> @a.DishPrice </h1>
}
```

As suggested by [@Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos), the above code could be written as:

```
@a.DishPrice?.ToString("00000.00")
```

---

Although that's possible, however, I believe adding a `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:00000.00}")]` is the easiest way:

```
public class Dish
{
    public int DishID { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:00000.00}")]
    public decimal? DishPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating a new object the OP could just call `String.Format()` or `ToString()` in place, eg `@a.DishPrice?.ToString("00000.00")`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your suggestion is much more efficient than mine. I'll update my answer. Thanks so much :)